# Multi Upsert ArangoDB

Tags: node.js, arangodb

My collection:

```
{"date": "5-1-2020", "country": "US", score: 0}
{"date": "5-1-2020", "country": "CA", score: 10}
{"date": "5-2-2020", "country": "US", score: 7}
{"date": "5-2-2020", "country": "CA", score: 11}
```

Here is the scenario: I need to update the score for the US game on 5-1-2020 to 17.

Pseudocode:

```
Search for date: "5-1-2020" and country "US".
If found UPDATE score to 17.
If not found insert record of {"date": "5-1-2020", "country": "US", score: 17}
```

My working solution:

```
FOR doc in collection

UPSERT { "date": "5-1-2020", "country": "US" }

INSERT doc

UPDATE { "score": 17 } in collection
```

If my collection was:

```
{"date": "5-1-2020", "country": "CA", score: 10}
{"date": "5-2-2020", "country": "US", score: 7}
{"date": "5-2-2020", "country": "CA", score: 11}
```

The solution/upsert doesn't work.

Comment: Do you actually want to copy all documents from `collection` to `newcol` while updating certain documents? Or do you want to take one matching document from `collection` and insert it into `newcol`, potentially with an updated score?

Comment: Sorry, updated the code. The collection names were supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean to do is this:

```
UPSERT { "date": "5-1-2020", "country": "US" }
INSERT { "date": "5-1-2020", "country": "US", "score": 17 }
UPDATE { "score": 17 } IN collection
```

Find document based on date and country and update its score, or insert a new document with date, country and score. Note that there is no outer FOR loop, which would iterate over the collection unnecessarily and potentially cause the same update to be performed hundred of times.